# AS3 1120 Error on instantiating

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I am trying to create a basic functionality in AS3.

I have a class like this:

```
package tax 
{
    public class Calculator
    {

        public function Calculator() 
        {
        }

        private var grwage:Number;
        private var taxes:Number;
        private var superannuation:Number;
        private var insurance:Number;
        private var net:Number;

        public function getGrwage():Number {
            return grwage;
        } 

        public function setGrwage(grwage:Number):void {
            this.grwage = grwage;
        }

        public function getTaxes():Number {
            return grwage;
        } 

        public function setTaxes(taxes:Number):void {
            this.taxes = grwage * 0.2;
        }

        public function getSup():Number {
            return superannuation;
        } 

        public function setSup(superannuation:Number):void {
            this.superannuation = superannuation * 0.05;
        }

        public function getIns():Number {
            return insurance;
        } 

        public function setIns(insurance:Number):void {
            this.insurance = insurance * 0.1;
        }

        public function getNet():Number {
            return net;
        } 

        public function setNet(net:Number):void {
            this.net = grwage - taxes - superannuation - insurance;
        }

    }
}
```

Just some getters and setters.

And in my mxml file:

```
        import tax.Calculator;

                    public var calculate:Calculator = new Calculator();

        calculate.setGrwage(1000);
        trace(calculate.getTaxes());
        trace(calculate.getSup());
        trace(calculate.getIns());
        trace(calculate.getNet());
```

I get an error 1120 Access to undefinded property when I try to access calculate. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the point of `setTaxes(taxes:Number)` if it doesn't use the given parameter?

Comment: Which one is it bugging out on? Can you paste the full error from the compiler?

Comment: There's nothing syntactically wrong with your code that I can see, but you do have some confusion about what getters and setters should be doing, and just basic mistakes like getTaxes() returning grwage instead of taxes, and setTaxes() and setNet() not actually being setters; you should have called those calculateTaxes() and calculateNet() if they are meant to calculate and store the result. Also, your code sample is going to trace 1000, NaN, NaN, NaN when you get it running, because you're getting things that haven't been set (only grwage is set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're mixing up things a bit between getters and setters. If a variable depends on another, you have to write the calculation in its getter. This variable shouldn't exist as a private member and the accesses to it must always be done through the appropriate getter.

for example:

```
public function getNet():Number {
    return getGrwage() - getTaxes() - getSup() - getIns();
}
```

So here, you only need one setter (setGrwage), you can remove the others ones and put the calculation in the getters.

Note that there is a more appropriate [syntax](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html) for setters and getters in AS3.

```
class GetSet 
{ 
    private var privateProperty:String; 

    public function get publicAccess():String 
    { 
        return privateProperty; 
    } 

    public function set publicAccess(setValue:String):void 
    { 
        privateProperty = setValue; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kodiak, I changed my class. But I still have the problem with the instantiating. It says "1120 Access of undefinded property calculate".

Comment: Is the code you posted like it is in your mxml? you should put the code (from calculate.setGrwage to the end) inside an event listener such as creationComplete.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your class. So lets redesign it
The main issue you had was you were not initiating the vars before you accessed them as they had a NULL value the flash player was throwing you that error.
As you can see in the constructor I set a default value of 0 so that they will never be NULL.

```
package tax {
    public class Calculator{

        private var _grwage:Number;
        private var _taxes:Number;
        private var _superannuation:Number;
        private var _insurance:Number;

        public function Calculator() {
          this._grwage = 0;
          this._taxes = 0;
          this._superannuation = 0;
          this._insurance = 0;
        }

        public function get grwage():Number {
            return this._grwage;
        } 

        public function set grwage(val:Number):void {
            this._grwage = val;
        }

        public function get taxes():Number {
            return this._taxes;
        } 

        public function set taxes(val:Number):void {
            this._taxes = val * 0.2;
        }

        public function get superannuation():Number {
            return this._superannuation;
        } 

        public function set superannuation(val:Number):void {
            this._superannuation = val * 0.05;
        }

        public function get insurance():Number {
            return this._insurance;
        } 

        public function set insurance(val:Number):void {
            this._insurance = val* 0.1;
        }

        public function get net():Number {
            return this._grwage -  this._taxes -  this._superannuation -  this._insurance;
        }

    }
}
```

```
    import tax.Calculator;
    public var calculate:Calculator = new Calculator();
     //Now due to the fact we are using true setter/getter methods.
    calculate.grwage = 1000;
    trace( calculate.taxes); // should be 0 as we are defaulting to the initial value
    trace( calculate.superannuation );// should be 0 as we are defaulting to the initial value
    trace( calculate.insurance );// should be 0 as we are defaulting to the initial value
    trace( calculate.net );// should be 1000 as we are defaulting to the initial values of everything but grwage
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are all good, but they all miss the primary point:

*You're trying to get your variables before you set them.*

```
import tax.Calculator;

public var calculate:Calculator = new Calculator();

calculate.setGrwage(1000);
trace(calculate.getTaxes());
trace(calculate.getSup());
trace(calculate.getIns());
trace(calculate.getNet());
```

This will throw an error (due to the way you've set up your class), because you never called `setSup()`, `setIns()`, and `setNet()` before trying to use them.

While your class may not be written in the best way, it is syntactically sound.

Try calling each setter before your getter. I think you'll solve your issue.